# How to add a column to an object/result of a powershell expression?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following PowerShell command:

```bsh
dir -r packages.config | % { ([xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)).packages.package; $_.DirectoryName }
```

Which parses the XML files packages.config and yields the following output for the 3 element attributes:

```
id                                 version        targetFramework
--                                 -------        ---------------
log4net                            2.0.0          net45          
Newtonsoft.Json                    8.0.3          net45          
protobuf-net                       2.0.0.621      net45          
C:\code\Services\TestProfile
EntityFramework                    6.1.1          net45          
log4net                            2.0.0          net45          
Newtonsoft.Json                    8.0.3          net45          
protobuf-net                       2.0.0.621      net45          
C:\code\Services\Tests
```

Note the directory name is appended after the tabular output (i.e. not an id in a new row).

How do I get the directory name to appear as a 4th column of each row, rather than an additional row after each XML table?

Like this:

```
id                                 version        targetFramework  Path
--                                 -------        ---------------  ----
log4net                            2.0.0          net45            C:\code\Services\TestProfile
Newtonsoft.Json                    8.0.3          net45            C:\code\Services\TestProfile
protobuf-net                       2.0.0.621      net45            C:\code\Services\TestProfile
EntityFramework                    6.1.1          net45            C:\code\Services\Tests
log4net                            2.0.0          net45            C:\code\Services\Tests
Newtonsoft.Json                    8.0.3          net45            C:\code\Services\Tests
protobuf-net                       2.0.0.621      net45            C:\code\Services\Tests
```

Snippet from packages.config, to illustrate the XML structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: `%{$Path = $_.DirectoryName; ([xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)).packages.package |Select *,@{L='Path';E={$Path}}`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen!  Move it to an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` with a calculated property!

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse packages.config |ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.DirectoryName
    ([xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)).packages.package |Select-Object *,@{L='Path';E={$Path}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this cuts out after the first packages.config found.  The dir -r finds multiple package.config files, but for some reason only the first file is being emitted.

Comment: Cuts out? I'm sorry but I'm not able to reproduce that behavior. With two different packages.config files in different folders I get the expected output

Comment: Shoot, you are right.  I was running the command from one of the sub-directories rather than the root.  Well done, and sorry for the confusion.